# The $R/I$-module $F/IF$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $F = \oplus_{i = 1}^r Re_i$ be a free $R$-module and $I\subset R$ be an ideal and $IF = \{ if :i \in I, f \in F \}$ is a submodule of $F$. Then
>   (1) $F/IF$ is an $R/I$-module and
>   (2) $\{e_i + IF \}$ form a basis of the $R/I$-module $F/IF.$

So the set $F/IF$ is defined as $ \{x + IF : x \in F \}$.

(1) So one has to prove that

(i) $(F/IF, +)$ is abelian (isn't this actually free?)

(ii) $F/IF$ satisfies the four axioms? This seems long if I were to do this one by one by cosets

I a not sure if this is the right procedure, but loosely speaking (i'll write out a detailed one if there are some confusions) $(e_i)$ is a basis for $F$, so $e_i + IF$ spans $F/IF$ (since every element $a + if$ where $a \in  F$ is sum of $\sum c_ie_i + if$.) Then linear independence comes from that $\sum (a_i + I)(e_i + I) = 0 \implies a_ie_i \in IF$ where the weights $a_i + I$ are elements in $R/I$ with $a_i \in R$. Then maybe say that $a_i \in I$ so $a_i + I = 0$

Comment: No, you should definitely not check the axioms of being a module directly. You need to show that $IF$ is a submodule and that $I$ acts trivially on the quotient. Do you see why this is enough?

Comment: Are you familiar with submodules and quotients?

Comment: An $R/I$-module is the same as an $R$-module $M$ with $IM=0$.

Comment: @user26857 How is that not what $IF$ means?

Comment: @user26857 The thing written in the question, i.e. $\{if\mid i\in I,f\in F\}$.

Comment: @user26857 Woops, not sure how I missed the closure under addition missing.